How to hide an already open browser in Puppeter?
You need to open the browser and close it after 3 seconds
const browser = await (require('puppeteer')).launch({headless: false, defaultViewport: null,args: ['--start-maximized'] });
const page = await browser.newPage();
//
page.goto('https://web.telegram.org/a/', {timeout: -1});
//
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('how to hide browser?')
}, 3000);

I already know how to initially launch it with a hidden browser. But the problem is that I need to close it after a while

await browser.close()
its all in docs

I expressed myself incorrectly, not close but hide without stopping all processes

i think what you mean here is await page.close() then. you close tab, but not the browser, and you can work with it. i dont think thats possible to switch to headless:true once you launched the browser, if that is what you mean.
